# Difference between Jenkins log and generated package (lib prefix)

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, buildfarm, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to debug a failure in setting up the CMake variables for library installation.

1. I am inspecting the generated package (`ros-kinetic-eigenpy`, version 1.6.5-1) by installing in a new Kinetic docker. The pkg-config eigenpy.pc is installed in `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig`, while the library itself is in `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib`. This would suggest an issue setting up the `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR`.
2. After reviewing the [output of the latest Jenkins job](http://build.ros.org/job/Kdev__eigenpy__ubuntu_xenial_amd64/17/console#console-section-0), it appears there it correctly installs without the `x86_64-linux-gnu` prefix (in `devel_isolated`).

Am I missing something obvious here why on Jenkins it appears to install correctly but the packaged version on ros-testing has it using the prefix?

I appreciate any insights

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337554/difference-between-jenkins-log-and-generated-package-(lib-prefix)/) by [wxm](https://answers.ros.org/users/41136/wxm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The job output you're linking is for a devel job which tests the latest version of packages in a source repository. The job which builds the Kinetic eigenpy debian package is http://build.ros.org/job/Kbin_uX64__eigenpy__ubuntu_xenial_amd64__binary/

You can also run a local copy of the binarydeb job using the ros_buildfarm library: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/blob/master/doc/jobs/release_jobs.rst#run-the-release-job-locally

---

Originally posted by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) with karma: 906 on 2019-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wxm](https://answers.ros.org/users/41136/wxm/) on 2019-11-14**:
Thank you - this is what I was looking for.

It turns out the original problem is related to an old version of `debhelper` on kinetic. Versions `>10.2.1` solve the problem. I will work on a workaround.

**Comment by [wxm](https://answers.ros.org/users/41136/wxm/) on 2019-11-14**:
@nuclearsandwich: I have described the issue I am trying to debug with references in https://github.com/stack-of-tasks/eigenpy/issues/116. It boils down to the use of `GNUInstallDirs` using old versions of debhelper on 16.04 appending the architecture to `lib`. As such the pkgconfig files end up in `lib/arch/pkgconfig` while the library ends up in `lib/`. Is there a recommended workaround? (This is a REP136 released third-party package)